# Different contextMenu options in fancytree?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancytree

I'm using fancytree to display a simple treeview.  There are two 'node types' in the tree:  Groups (which can have children) and Items (which cannot have children).  I'm trying to use the contextMenu extension to add functionality.  There are three options on my menu:  Add, Edit, and Delete.  Is it possible to only have the 'Add' menu option display for the 'Group' nodes (their `key` value starts with a 'g') and not the 'Item' nodes?  Or at least have it be disabled for the 'Item' nodes??

```
var treeData = [{title: "All Locations", key: "g0", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [
                  {title: "Location 1", key: "g1", folder: true, children: [
                    {title: "Item 1", key: "81"},
                    {title: "Item 2", key: "82"},
                    {title: "Item 3", key: "83"},
                  ]},
                  {title: "Location 2", key: "g2", folder: true, children: [
                    {title: "Item 4", key: "87"},
                  ]},
                  {title: "Location 3", key: "g3", folder: true, expanded: true, children: [
                    {title: "Item 5", key: "88"},
                    {title: "Item 6", key: "89"},
                  ]}
               ]}
              ];

$(function(){
  // Create the tree inside the <div id="tree"> element.
  $("#tree").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    debugLevel: 2,
    selectMode: 3,
    extensions: ['contextMenu'],
    source: treeData,
    contextMenu: {
      menu: {
        "add": { "name": "Add", "icon": "add" },
        "edit": { "name": "Edit", "icon": "edit" },
        "delete": { "name": "Delete", "icon": "delete" },
      },
      actions: function(node, action, options) {
        alert('Selected action "' + action + '" on node ' + node.key);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Use 3rd part plugin : [contextmenu](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#../3rd-party/extensions/contextmenu/contextmenu.html)

And instead of describing menu items use function:

```
contextMenu: {
  menu: function(node){
  if (node.folder){                 
    return {
        'create':{ 'name': 'folder option', 'icon': 'paste'}
    };
   } else {
      return {
        'create':{ 'name': 'leaf option', 'icon': 'paste'}
       };
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be able to disable it.

Here is one way to do it, for disabling Edit/Delete buttons for the Root node. (May not be the best way, but possible direction for you to think about...)

For this, you could add "`beforeOpen`" property within `contextMenu`. This would be called once you right click for the context menu and before the menu actual appears.

```
beforeOpen: function(event, ui) {
    var node = $.ui.fancytree.getNode(ui.target);
    /* Is this the root node */
    if( node.getParentList().length == 0 )
    {
        $('.ui-menu-item').eq(1).prop('disabled', true);  //disable Edit
        $('.ui-menu-item').eq(2).prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.ui-menu-item').eq(1).prop('disabled', false);  //enable Edit
        $('.ui-menu-item').eq(2).prop('disabled', false);
    }
    node.setActive();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me.  I pasted your code between my 'menu' and 'actions' definitions in the 'contextMenu' section and added an alert box after the `var node =...` line.  The alert never displays and the context menu is fully active.

Comment: I think there could be API change. Are you using the latest version. Please check the sample usage. http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-menu.html

Comment: I had v2.0.0.  I just updated to v2.1.0 with the same results.  The sample link you gave goes to the deprecated `[menu]` extension, not the `[contextMenu]` extension.